# Where can I get feedback about a licensing open source tool?

Tags: licensing, osi

Existing tools intended to help in picking up a license for an OSS are not able to fully differentiate among them.

I propose this open source [tool](https://sihem.pythonanywhere.com) to help OSS authors in discovering, understanding and selecting OSI-approved open source licenses. It exhibits the terms dealt with in the licenses texts as features and compares licenses based on that. It also displays the licenses satisfying a set of selected features.

This is a research tool (for non-profit); and I need to collect feedback from its (potential) users (OSS developers and experts) in practice for evaluation purposes.

Is it right to share this knowledge and request here?

If yes, take a look to the [tool](https://sihem.pythonanywhere.com) and leave your valuable feedback through the "feedback" button in the home page or through this [link](https://sihem.pythonanywhere.com/questionnaire).

If not, where can I find OSS developers and OSS / legal experts that may be interested in and can help?

Comment: There seem to me to be two questions here.  The first, "*may I ask this here?*", is a question for our [Meta](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/) site.  The second, "*where else can I find developers etc?*" is an [external resources](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/q/688/458) question, which are also off-topic.  Further, you are still not disclosing your connection, if any, with this project, which you have been told you are required to do. I'm not going to close this immediately, but if it starts to accumulate close votes, I will endorse them.